# Ubuntu 21.04. Newbie here. Please confirm correctness before I do a Timeshift system restore

Tags: restore

Newbie here. See pics. Some of my apps got messed up and I want to do a Timeshift system restore to yesterday (Aug 10th). Please look at the pics and see if I’m all set to do a restore. Will this restore take my apps back to yesterday? I want to make sure cuz I know a bad restore can trash my whole system. Thanks.[image]

Comment: What do you mean "some of my apps got messed up"? Would it be fixable? To do a Timeshift restore, I believe that you've got to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, install Timeshift, point it at where your Timeshift backup files are located, and then restore from there.

Comment: See my comments on your earlier question about VLC/Flameshot.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.
I got it working. I took a deep breath and did my first Timeshift system restore and it worked! Flameshot and KDEConnect started working again, but my VLC snap was not working. I then removed the VLC snap and installed the VLC flatpak and that now is working normally. So I'm back to normal.
Thank goodness for Timeshift! Now I'll be doing system snapshots a lot more often (and properly commenting them).